# is it possible to create custom columns (such as checksum/hash column) in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, hashing

Is it possible to create my own custom column in Windows Explorer when listing files in "Details" mode? Right now, I have:

```
Name              Date Modified      Type       Size    Hash
```

I would like to be able to see something like:

```
Name              Date Modified      Type       Size    Hash
something.php     8/1/2013 2:34 AM   PHP file   9 KB    dfb6e8d87ea4450a286a4aba90294aea
anything.php      8/1/2013 2:34 AM   PHP file   9 KB    dfb6e8d87ea4450a286a4aba90294aea
something2.php    8/1/2013 2:34 AM   PHP file   9 KB    dfb6e8d87ea4450a286a4aba90294aea
```

Or, maybe, how about a way to easily determine which files are similar?

Comment: Related pointers for those that may be able to help you with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648275/display-custom-header-or-column-in-windows-explorer and https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/8f31b1ff79d669b4ba9609f2640635b3b8a9e0a4/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/RecipePropertyHandler and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728871(v=vs.85).aspx .... I'd like to see a nice detailed answer on this myself actually and that hash value sounds nice and without 3rd party too would be great even with dll, etc.

Comment: Would having a PowerShell GUI explorer with all those fields suffice rather than using Windows Explorer? If so, that may be another idea if someone has something maybe.

Comment: Since the others have mentioned it's impossible to create a custom column, might I just recommend Clonespy if you want to determine duplicate files. You have to launch it each time though, so it's not something you'll notice while browsing files.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the answer by @magicandre1981 is correct,
and it is no longer possible since Vista for an extension to add
a custom column to Windows Explorer. Only adding a custom property tab
is still supported.

If you wish to view files and their checksum, you will need to use
a third-party product.

One such product is [XYplorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/),
an alternative and very evolved file manager,
where this is one of its listed capabilities.
However, I was not able to check it out
since it is not enabled in the free version.
The paid version costs $39.95 with a 30-day trial.

Otherwise I am listing below two free viewer utilities that display
checksums.

[**QuickHash**](https://www.quickhash-gui.org/)

[image]

[**NirSoft HashMyFiles**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html)

[image: image2]

Answer (score 3):

[Creating Column Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776831%28VS.85%29.aspx) only worked until Windows XP and stopped working since Vista. A lot of tools like [folderSize](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) struggle with this change.

Answer (score 3):

I use [HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) Shell Extension.  Its not exactly what you are looking for, but it works and its free.  It adds checksums to the properties of a file/folder.  Also, it makes comparisons fairly easy.