# Showing GPS data on columns of Details layout of search results in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, photos

I'd like to show GPS data, latitude and longitude, of EXIF data of photo files (heic and jpeg) on columns of search results details layout in windows explorer (like in the first following link).

On my PC, there is a folder containing subfolders. Each subfolder contains photo files. I tried the following way to do the above and it works in subfolders directly containing photo files but it doesn't work with search results in the top-level folder (folder types of this folder and all subfolders are "Pictures") with the search keyword "* NOT kind:Folders".

[Windows Explorer - Details view - column for geolocation - Latitude and Longitude](https://superuser.com/questions/1342030/windows-explorer-details-view-column-for-geolocation-latitude-and-longitud)
The following is related to my question.
[GPS data in Explorer details view](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/gps-data-in-explorer-details-view/d27545b3-31f3-45a4-8aae-62c50afa47b6?page=1)

Could you tell me the way to do this?
If possible, it is preferable to be able to do so on Windows Explorer, not third-party software.
I would prefer the above solution of making changes to the registry to be valid for my case as well, but I don't know how to do it.

The following is related to my question, but this may be not valid for my case, Windows 10.
[is it possible to create custom columns (such as checksum/hash column) in windows explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/629509/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-columns-such-as-checksum-hash-column-in-window)

Comment: The following code is my solution.     `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}\TopViews\{5586158e-f4e6-409e-b47c-4d216f40b912}]
"ColumnList"="prop:0System.ItemNameDisplay;0System.ItemDate;0System.ItemTypeText;0System.Size;0System.Keywords;1System.GPS.Latitude;1System.GPS.Longitude;1System.GPS.Altitude;1System.DateCreated;1System.DateModified;1System.Photo.DateTaken;1System.Image.Dimensions;1System.Rating"
"IconSize"=dword:00000060
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
"Name"="NoName"
"Order"=dword:00000000`

Comment: I'm updating the code in my answer that you linked to. It will now modify the `Pictures`, `PIctures.SearchResults`, and `PIctures.Library` *FolderTYpes*...

Comment: Thank you very much, @Keith. 
Thanks to your posts, I can now manage my photos using GPS data, which makes my photo management much easier!